# Style SVG when used as sprite

Tags: css, svg

Is there a way, when using SVG sprites, to target the groups and paths inside the icon being used, relative to the parent container?

```
<a href="index.php" id="logo-type">
            <svg><use xlink:href="#logo"></use></svg>
        </a>
```

I want to be able to change the icons appearance on the application of another class to the parent container.

```
#logo-type{

        svg{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;

            ellipse{ fill: blue;}
       g {stroke:red;} 

        } 


    &.active {  

        ellipse{ fill: yellow;}
       g {stroke:purple;} 

    }

}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wsmGF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using symbols &/or defs (AFAIK) you have to give the `<use>` it's own ID/Class and target that

**HTML**

```
<a href="index.php" id="logo-type" class="active">
  <svg><use id="used" xlink:href="#logo"></use></svg>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#used {
  stroke:white; /* works */
}

#used #pg { /* doesn't work */
  fill:red;
}
```

**However, you cannot target individual paths etc *within* the `<use>`**...AFAIK

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/nbJsm)